# How to make a common mirror for Ubuntu and Mint Linux?

Tags: apt, server, repository, mint, apt-mirror

The mirror for Ubuntu repositories is created using this link: https://blog.programster.org/set-up-a-local-ubuntu-mirror-with-apt-mirror

and the mirror for Mint repositories is created using this link: 
http://www.linuxwolfpack.com/linux-mint-mirror-13.php

I wish to create a common mirror for both the distributions. What do I have to do for making this happen?

Comment: these 2 distributions look alike some, but aren't the same, so just create 2 distinct folders (one for Ubuntu and the other one for Mint)

Comment: Yes, I could gather that, but I was looking for something more deep!

Comment: you must ask Ubuntu dev team, I think you can rely on your fingers about the number of members which will know a litlle about common mirror repo here, and not so many here know much about mirror repo   D: